# Swift - how to define a type constraint that guarantee the type has an init

Tags: swift, generics

I have following code:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var v: Int = 1
}

func createInstance<T: Any>(type: T.Type) -> T
{
    return type.init()
}

let myType = MyStruct.self
let instance = createInstance(type: myType)
```

This does not work because I do not guarantee, the T has an init.

```
Playground execution failed: error: MyPlayground.playground:76:12: error: type 'T' has no member 'init'
return type.init()
       ^~~~ ~~~~
```

But how can I define a constraint which guarantees the type has an init?

Comment: Can you have an `Initializable` protocol that these structs and classes have to implement?

Comment: Do you mean just an empty protocol they must implement? Hm a bit odd but it sounds like a nice trick :) I will give it a try.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with `createInstance(type:)`? There's a reason that there's no `DefaultConstructible` (or similar) protocol in the standard library – without any accompanying semantics, *just* being initialisable isn't that meaningful. I would recommend having a read of [Protocols are more than Bags of Syntax](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/12/protocols-have-semantics/).

Comment: I write a framework to easy persist structs and classes. In the load func I don't know users types of course so I need to pass them and create instances of them.

Comment: @Dareon Ah okay, so you want a protocol that represents something that can be encoded/decoded (not just *anything* that can be constructed). But surely in that case you'd actually want an initialiser requirement that took one (or more) parameter(s), in order to pass a decoder/dictionary/etc. to the type so that it can be properly initialised with its decoded property values?

Comment: @Hamish Sure there is more as an guaranteed init, this was just a partial problem I had to solve to be able to return expected instances. I have read your block on the DefaultConstructible and understand the thoughts about correct and meaningful APIs. On the other hand if one is able to create his own protocol with nothing more than init() in it, is all responsibility for sane code on him. In this case we don't need Swift-Home-Protocol like that at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *could* construct a custom protocol that blueprints the `init()` method, and use this protocol as a type constraint for the generic typeholder in your `createInstance` function. E.g.:

```
protocol SimplyInitializable {
    init()
}

struct MyStruct: SimplyInitializable {
    var v: Int = 1
}

func createInstance<T: SimplyInitializable>(type: T.Type) -> T
{
    return type.init()
}

let myType = MyStruct.self
let instance = createInstance(type: myType)
```

Type that (explicitly) conforms to `SimplyInitializable` above will be able to make use of the `createInstance` method (note the conformance of `MyStruct` to `SimplyInitializable`).

---

As an alternative to the approach above, you could likewise, if you'd like, make use of a generic `struct` rather than a global generic `createInstance` method to create instances of types that conform to `SimplyInitializable`. E.g.:

```
protocol SimplyInitializable {
    init()
}

struct SimpleFactory<T: SimplyInitializable> {
    static func createInstance() -> T {
        return T.init()
    }
}

struct MyStruct: SimplyInitializable {
    var v: Int = 1
}

let instance = SimpleFactory<MyStruct>.createInstance()
```

Comment: Perfect, I've wrongly tried protocol with func init(). Thank you.

Comment: @Dareon happy to help. Make sure also to have a look at the very related and relevant blog post linked to by Hamish in a comment to your question above. The answer above shows you _how_, technically, you could achieve the functionality you're asking about, whereas the blog post discusses why protocols such as `SimplyInitializable` above have very poor semantic value, and would be a bad idea to implement e.g. in the stdlibs of Swift.

Comment: @dfri these might have poor generic value, but c# solves this quite elegantly by providing a `new()` generic type constraint